# Sql query to combine result of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I am using the following query to display the following result.

```
SELECT * FROM RouteToGrowthRecord, GradeMaster,MileStoneMaster
WHERE MemberID = 'ALV01L11034A06' AND
RouteToGrowthRecord.GradeID=GradeMaster.GradeID AND
RouteToGrowthRecord.MileStoneID=MileStoneMaster.MileStoneID 
ORDER BY CheckupDate DESC
```

[image: and the output of quiry is:]

Now I have another table named `RouteToGrowthRecord_st` that has same
columns as `RouteToGrowthRecord` with some additional fields.

I need to display result that are present in both the table. ie . if `RouteToGrowthRecord_st` has 3 records with the given `menberID`,then output must contain 3 more records along with the above query result.(fr ex above its 9+3=12 records in total).

Comment: use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: @diEcho: not JOIN, UNION.  read the question more carefully.

Comment: @ysth : Oh! I havn't read with care and just gave the suggestions .

Comment: how to use UNION? can anyone give me the quiery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Union here to merge the results getting from both queries. Use default values for the unmapped additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT * FROM RouteToGrowthRecord a inner join GradeMaster b inner 
  join MileStoneMaster c inner join  RouteToGrowthRecord_st d on 
    a.GradeID=b.GradeID AND   a.MileStoneID=c.MileStoneID   and
    d.GradeID=b.GradeID AND  d.MileStoneID=c.MileStoneID 
    WHERE a.MemberID = 'ALV01L11034A06' 
    ORDER BY CheckupDate DESC
```

Comment: which table contain coloumn MmberID ? RouteToGrowthRecord ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write above query in following way

```
SELECT * FROM RouteToGrowthRecord 
INNER JOIN GradeMaster ON  RouteToGrowthRecord.GradeID=GradeMaster.GradeID
INNER JOIN MileStoneMaster ON RouteToGrowthRecord.MileStoneID=MileStoneMaster.MileStoneID
LEFT JOIN RouteToGrowthRecord_st ON    RouteToGrowthRecord_st.memberID=RouteToGrowthRecord.memberID 
WHERE
RouteToGrowthRecord.MemberID = 'ALV01L11034A06'
order by CheckupDate DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> **this is my answer**

```
SELECT CheckUpDate,AgeInMonths,PresentWeight,Height,Diagnosis,growthstatus,GradeName,MilestoneName,MemberID
FROM RouteToGrowthRecord, GradeMaster,MileStoneMaster WHERE
 MemberID = 'ALV01L56107A11  ' and 
  RouteToGrowthRecord.GradeID=GradeMaster.GradeID and 
  RouteToGrowthRecord.MileStoneID=MileStoneMaster.MileStoneID 
  union
  SELECT CheckUpDate,AgeInMonths,PresentWeight,Height,Diagnosis,growthstatus,GradeName,MilestoneName,MemberID
   FROM RouteToGrowthRecord_st, GradeMaster,MileStoneMaster WHERE
 MemberID = 'ALV01L56107A11  ' and 
  RouteToGrowthRecord_st.GradeID=GradeMaster.GradeID and 
  RouteToGrowthRecord_st.MileStoneID=MileStoneMaster.MileStoneID 
  order by CheckupDate DESC
```